# Filing color like effect in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-animation, core-graphics

I am trying to make a "feeling app" which has an image which will change its color up to that location where the user touches it. I implemented `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for that and found the touch but was unable to change the color of that particular part of the image.

Comment: What is the "image" that you are trying to fill? Vector or bitmap? How do you define changing the color of a "particular part of the image"?

Comment: is there any specific reason is there for going to pan gesture?... this stuff can be able to do in touches stuff...

Comment: actually i want to fill a thermometer image with different color on UI on dragging level up and down.Thats why I chosen pan gesture.

Comment: This effect will like as filling a glass by touching  it and moving up and then depleting it as finger moved down on the image.

Answer (score 1):

try this block of code....

you want to change color means change the stokeColor and you want to change size of the brush means  see the commented line

```
#pragma mark touches stuff...

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView];

   }

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView];

    CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);  // u can change the brush size here

       CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor); // u need to change this to required color

            CGContextSetBlendMode(context,kCGBlendModeDarken ); // try the various blend modes

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:imageView];
}
```

i hope this will help you...